# Access Files on Host from Privileged Container

Tags: kubernetes, containers

How can I read a file on the host from within a privileged container?

I can't mount any volumes as I do not control how the container is created, but I can at least request a container in privileged mode. That should be good enough to read a file on the host, right? But what would I have to do?

TL;DR

I am running [Concourse](https://concourse.ci) (CI/CD tool) in a Kubernetes cluster, but unfortunately it is not deploying its jobs as regular Kubernetes pods, but as [Garden](https://github.com/cloudfoundry/garden) containers.

My problem is that I need to access the default Kubernetes service to interact with the hosting cluster (every pod can), but I can't do that from within a spawned (nested) Garden container without the token that is mounted in the pod that is running Concourse. The only configuration option is to make the (nested) Garden container privileged.

So, how can I read a file on the host from within a privileged container?

I can't mount any volumes as I do not control how the container is created, but I can at least request a container in privileged mode. That should be good enough to read a file on the host (i.e. in the pod, since the Garden container is nested inside the pod container), right? But what would I have to do?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried [DIND](https://blog.docker.com/2013/09/docker-can-now-run-within-docker/)? I've never tried it (as I've never had a situation where I wanted to do that) but it sounds almost exactly like what you want, provided they haven't stripped your outer docker invocation of the capabilities it would need to pull off such a thing

Comment: DIND is not what I am after here. In fact, Concourse is doing that with `runc`. What I need to do is to reach out from within a privileged runc container into the surrounding Docker container (spawned by Kubernetes) and read some files (provided by Kubernetes; the files I need to access the Kubernetes cluster control plane).